# How to convert a date a user selects in MM-dd-yyyy format to the format yyyy-MM-dd in Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I want to convert the incoming date from MM-dd-yyyy which is the format on the front end, and convert it to the format yyyy-MM-dd.  This is useful since the backend query requires the format to be yyyy-MM-dd.  I am having trouble with the syntax.  I know when I do Date = new Date(), that only initializes for today's date but I want the paramater to be the incoming date that the user selects, which can be whatever it wants to be.  I have two date formats set up:

```
public final static String getConvertedDate()
{
    DateFormat userFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(MM-dd-yyyy);
    DateFormat neededFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(yyyy-MM-dd);
    //now I want to set it up to where I have a date the user selects
    Date date = new Date() //I feel like I should input a parameter for any given date in Date() but am    //unsure
    //return statement returning the neededFormat
}
```

I may or may not be setting it up properly and am unsure if I need to set up two DateFormats like that.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the user-selected date.  How is it getting into this function?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

You said, you want to convert a date with a given format, but you don't have a parameter for that.

```
public final static String getConvertedDate(String givenDaten) throws ParseException
{
    DateFormat userFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(MM-dd-yyyy);
    DateFormat neededFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(yyyy-MM-dd);

    //first parse the userformatted date
    Date userFormatDate = userFormat.parse(givenDate);

    //format it as needed
    return neededFormat.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the `format` function for `SimpleDateFormat`

A quick example would be

```
public final static String getConvertedDate(String userDate)
{
    DateFormat userFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(MM-dd-yyyy);
    DateFormat neededFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(yyyy-MM-dd);

    // Turn the String of the userDate into a date with the first format
    Date formatUserDate = userFormat.parse(userDate);

    // Now format that date into the correct format you want to return
    return neededFormat.format(formatUserDate);
}
```

Comment: I can see that I need to format the incoming date, however that date can't just be a manual input.  08-10-1999 or just something to throw in there is not what I'm looking for, I want the parameter to be just whatever a user would select, which could be anything.

Comment: Let me change it for you

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
public String convertDate(String input) throws ParseException{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    Date temp = sdf.parse(input);
    sdf.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return sdf.format(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually *parse* the input `String` using your `DateFormat`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final DateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    final Date date = in.parse("03-11-2013");
    System.out.println(date);
    final DateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println(out.format(date));
}
```

Output:

```
Mon Mar 11 00:00:00 CET 2013
2013-03-11
```

Note, you're probably better off using the `Date` object in your code. JDBC can accept the `Date` with only a simple conversion to a `java.sql.Date` and you can convert it to any format your need later.

I would also promote the formats for class members as they are expensive to construct so should be reused, although it should be noted that they are not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "01-23-2017" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" ) 
).toString()
```

> 2017-01-23

## Using java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by java.time classes.

```
String input = "01-23-2017" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

Your desired output happens to be standard ISO 8601. The java.time classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

> 2017-01-23

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).